# Configure Sphinx to index dash and search it with and without it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

I have a record

```
Item id: 1, name: "wd-40"
```

How do I configure Sphinx to match this record on the following queries:

```
Item.search("wd40")
Item.search("wd-40")
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your title question, `charset_table` is what you want.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#charsets

---

But that doesnt actully solve the query of matching those two queries, indexing - wouldn't work, just be the inverse of indexing it.

Instead, you probably want `ignore_chars`

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-ignore-chars

Answer (score 0):

First indexing:

By default, only ascii characters are indexed by Sphinx; the others are considered word separators. To fix that, you need to use the [`charset_table`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#charsets) parameter to map the dash to the dash character.

Second searching:

AFAIK, it is not possible to make Sphinx to consider both searches like you are asking for. However, you can just use something like:

```
# in Python, but I believe is understandable
query = word
if '-' in word:
    query += " | " + word.replace('-','')
Item.search(query)  # if word = 'wd-40', query = 'wd-40 | wd40'
```

Comment: Yes, I added this because the question doesn't mention if the objective is to lose information about the hyphens on the index, or just a way to be able to search them. I think both approaches are valid, depending on the objective. What I forgot was to +1 yours in any case. ;)